# Excel DNA in VB.NET error “Xcopy exited with code 9009”

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, visual-studio, excel-dna

I am getting the following error:

```
 The command "xcopy 
    "C:\Dev3.5\SygniaPlatinum\\packages\ExcelDna.AddIn.0.33.9\tools\ExcelDna.xll"
    "C:\Dev3.5\PlatinumXL3\PlatinumXL3\bin\x86\Debug\PlatinumXL3-AddIn.xll*" /C /Y
    exited with code 9009.
```

I think the issue is the path `'C:\Dev3.5\SygniaPlatinum\\packages\...'` where there are two `\\`'s in the filename. I cant seem to find where this is specified to modify it. Its not in the code, I have searched the entire project.

Can anyone assist...

Comment: The double backslashes are not the problem - xcopy should work fine with them if the rest of the paths are fine.

Comment: MSBuild just sees a failure exit code, it doesn't know why the post-build event failed.  Look in the Output window for the actual xcopy error message.

Answer (score 0):

The double backslashes are not the problem - xcopy should work fine with them if the rest of the paths are fine. The commands are specified in the post-build events. If you moved the project after installing the ExcelDna.AddIn package, it might go wrong. Easiest is to uninstall all the ExcelDna.XXX packages, then install ExcelDna.AddIn again. That should fix the paths.